# Combining filter and exlude in Django query on related objects gives empty results

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I want to do the following query in Django to find car objects whose manufacturer doesn't exist in manufacturers table and have a specific country code:

```
ids = Countries.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
Cars.objects.filter(group__manufacturer__country=123).exclude(group__manufacturer__id__in=ids)
```

Unfortunately this gives me an empty query result. But executing the filter and exclude query alone gives non empty results where some of the objects are the same (i.e. fullfill both conditions). Therefore I'm wondering how to combine the queries to get the correct subset. I also tried using Djangos Q objects but unfortunately with the same results. If possible I would want to avoid using raw sql.

Edit:

SQL query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM "car"
   INNER JOIN "group" ON ("cars"."group_id" = "group"."id")
   INNER JOIN "manufacturertogroup" ON ("group"."id" = "manufacturertogroup"."group_id")
   WHERE (NOT ("cars"."group_id"
       IN (SELECT V2."group_id" FROM "manufacturertogroup" V2
       WHERE (V2."country" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "countries" U0)
       AND V2."group_id" IS NOT NULL))
       AND "cars"."group_id" IS NOT NULL)
       AND "manufacturertogroup"."country" = 123)
```

Comment: why not try `exclude` first and `filter` after?

Comment: I did but this didn't help either.

Comment: have you logged the `SQL` query generated by this and see if there's something wrong there?

Comment: `group__manufacturer__id__in=ids` - `ids` does not seem to be a list of manufacturer ids. It is a list of cars.

Comment: You need to show all models involved to be able to help. The query alone is not sufficient.

Comment: I corrected an error in retrieving the list of ids (should be country ids and obviously not car ids) and added the sql query that Django creates (slightly summarized on unimportant parts).

Comment: Check if `Cars.objects.filter(group__manufacturer__country=123).values_list('group__manufacturer__id',flat=True)` and `Countries.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)` are returning same set of ids

Comment: If you already have `equal` filter on country, why would you want to have one more filter (`exclude`) on country?

Comment: It's likely a data error -- it's probable that rows where manufacturergroup.country == 123 either don't exist or have group ids that are in the Country table